# Jil serializer ignore null properties

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, jsonserializer, jil

Is there an attribute to prevent Jil from serializing properties that are null ?

In Newtonsoft it is :

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/issues/155?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the whole object, the `excludeNulls` parameter on [`Options`](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/blob/203d47c9f109401fa8045a1a3f079e63678b1f14/Jil/Options.cs#L375) is what you want (many different Options configurations are pre-calced, anything like `Options.ExcludeNulls` also works).

You can control serialization of a single property with [Conditional Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(VS.71).aspx).  (I forgot about this option in my original answer).

For example

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public string DontSerializeIfNull {get;set;}
    public string AlwaysSerialize {get;set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializeDontSerializeIfNull()
    {
        return DontSerializeIfNull != null;
    }
}

JSON.Serialize(new ExampleClass { DontSerializeIfNull = null, AlwaysSerialize = null });
// {"AlwaysSerialize":null}

JSON.Serialize(new ExampleClass { DontSerializeIfNull = "foo", AlwaysSerialize = null });
// {"AlwaysSerialize":null,"DontSerializeIfNull":"foo"}

JSON.Serialize(new ExampleClass { DontSerializeIfNull = null, AlwaysSerialize = "bar" });
// {"AlwaysSerialize":"bar"}

JSON.Serialize(new ExampleClass { DontSerializeIfNull = "foo", AlwaysSerialize = "bar" });
// {"AlwaysSerialize":"bar","DontSerializeIfNull":"foo"}
```

Jil only respects the `Name` option on `[DataMember]`.  I suppose honoring `EmitDefaultValue` wouldn't be the hardest thing, but nobody's ever opened an [issue](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/issues) for it.

Comment: Does Jil recognize the "ShouldSerialize" method or somthing should be add ?

Comment: @guyAssaf Conditional Serialization in .NET is adding an instance method returning `bool` with the name `ShouldSerializeXXX()` for property `XXX`.  Jil respects that.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: How can I do it, When I want Ignore all null values globally. Like I do in JSON.net `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                            .Formatters
                            .JsonFormatter
                            .SerializerSettings
                            .NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;` in gloabl.asax.cs file

Comment: @AmitKumar you can call [`JSON.SetDefaultOptions(Options)`](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/blob/75ffc895d0483fccb60a45d2bdcbaf4c78604496/Jil/JSON.cs#L29) to set global configurations.  These can still be overridden by passing an `Options` object at the callsite.